# IOS:Generate 32 bit CRC algotithm

Tags: ios, iphone, core-bluetooth, crc32

I am doing iOS app which requires to generate 32 bit crc algorithm. Based on the Core Bluetooth app that needs to communicate with the watch device iPhone device which act as a central device needs to send command  to watch as below.

```
  - (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:  
   (CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
 {
  [SharedData sharedConstants].verifyMode = 1;
  [ObjBLEConnection verifyMode:[ObjBLEConnection activePeripheral]];
  [ObjBLEConnection enableButtons:[ObjBLEConnection activePeripheral]];
   NSString *characteristicUUIDstring = TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID;
                CBUUID *characteristicUUID = [CBUUID  
     UUIDWithString:characteristicUUIDstring];
     int comm[6];
     comm[0]=0x01;
     comm[1]=6;
   comm[2]=0x70;
   comm[3]=0x00;
   comm[4]=0xFFFF;
   comm[5]=0xFFFF;
   NSMutableArray *arr=[[NSMutableArray  alloc]initWithCapacity:6];
   for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:comm[i]];
    [arr addObject:number];
    }
    NSLog(@"mutable arr is %@",arr);
    NSString *error1;
   NSData *dataarr = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:arr   
   format:NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error1];
CBMutableCharacteristic *testCharacteristic = [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:characteristicUUID properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyRead|CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite value:dataarr permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadable|CBAttributePermissionsWriteable];
NSLog(@"Read or Write %@ ",testCharacteristic);

                [peripheral writeValue:dataarr forCharacteristic:testCharacteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
NSString *error2;
NSData *dataarr2 = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:testCharacteristic.value format:NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error2];
NSLog(@"data is %@",dataarr2);

}
```

Here the commands comm[4] and comm[5] need to generate a value by using the crc algorithm by taking above comm commands that is used to send to the watch device. In response to that watch give some data. I need to get that data and show in my app. Is there any snippet of code related to generate  crc algorithms and send to hardware device. Please help

Comment: Who requires it, and what CRC do they specify?  There are many different 32-bit CRCs.  By the way, your "clear explanation" isn't.  Also please learn to put spaces after your periods.

Comment: i have edited the code please find above